# Write to european CSV, decimals converted for normal data frame but not with "aggregated" data frame

Tags: r, write.table

While a normal data frame such as "test" below, works perfectly in converting decimal "." to ",":

```
a <- c(1:34)
b <- rnorm(34, mean=33, sd=7)
test <- cbind.data.frame(a,b)
write.table(file="test.csv",test, row.names = F, dec=",", sep = ";")
```

My other data frame does not come out with "," as decimal. I am guessing that the upstream usage of "grep" and "aggregate" somehow is an obstacle for the conversion. Str output below, says three variables when I have five. How do I prepare the data frame to be accessable for decimal conversion?

```
   Group.1                Group.2       x.mean         x.sd         x.cv
1       P1      Compound 1:  IgG1  11.94520000   0.11435889   0.95736270
2       P2      Compound 1:  IgG1  10.29220000   0.06536700   0.63511201
3       P1      Compound 2:  IgG2  10.07450000   0.05682967   0.56409417
4       P2      Compound 2:  IgG2  19.66320000   0.16354259   0.83171908
...



'data.frame':   12 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Group.1: Factor w/ 10 levels "","FBS","ID",..: 9 10 9 10 9 10 9 10 9 10 ...
$ Group.2: Factor w/ 11 levels "Compound 1:  IgG1",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
$ x      : num [1:12, 1:3] 11.95 10.29 10.07 19.66 4.21 ...
 ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 .. ..$ : NULL
 .. ..$ : chr  "mean" "sd" "cv"
```

Output from `dput`.

```
structure(list(Group.1 = structure(c(9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L
), .Label = c("", "FBS", "ID", "K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "K5", 
"P1", "P2"), class = "factor"), Group.2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Compound 1:  IgG1", "Compound 2:  IgG2", 
"Compound 3:  IgG3", "Compound 4:  IgG3-723", "Compound 5:  IgG4", 
"Compound 6:  Total-IgG", "Compound 7:  IgG1_IS", "Compound 8:  IgG2_IS", 
"Compound 9:  IgG3_IS", "Compound 10:  IgG4_IS", "Compound 11:  Total_IgG_IS"
), class = "factor"), x = structure(c(11.9452, 10.2922, 10.0745, 
19.6632, 4.2135, 3.7465, 0.114358889272131, 0.0653669981293651, 
0.0568296675259594, 0.163542587046242, 0.0569370997973496, 0.0253651116474753, 
0.957362700265639, 0.63511200840797, 0.564094173665784, 0.831719084616146, 
1.35130176331671, 0.677034876484061), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("mean", "sd", "cv")))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you add a sample of your data frame to the question. To solve the problem it is often necessary to reproduce it. Use the `dput` function (or `dput(head())` for a large data frame) and paste the result here.

Comment: Notice that your `$ x` is a ***matrix***, not a "normal column". But when I try `dat <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=2:4); dat$z <- matrix(1:6 + 0.1, nrow=3); write.table(dat, "foo.csv", dec=",", sep = ";", row.names=FALSE)`, it indeed has commas correctly, where the first row of data shows `1;2;1,1;4,1`.

Comment: `readr` in the `tidyverse` has `write_csv2` which will automatically format it how you want it. `readr::write_csv2(test, "test.csv")`

Comment: @Jan, I will try dput and come back with the output.

Comment: I thank you for your effort @r2evans.

Comment: @allisonrs, I am on a loaner-computer ten more days so I will have to do with base R.

Comment: @Jan, I have added the `dput`-output above.

Answer (score 1):

@r2evans had the right hunch. The problem is `test$x` which is a matrix and that is the source of the problem. The output you get does not make sense at all and does not represent the data well. If you include the matrix columns directly into the data frame, it works as expected.

```r
test <- structure(
  list(Group.1 = structure(
    c(9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L), 
    .Label = c("", "FBS", "ID", "K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "K5", "P1", "P2"), 
    class = "factor"), 
    Group.2 = structure(
      c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
      .Label = c("Compound 1:  IgG1", "Compound 2:  IgG2", "Compound 3:  IgG3", 
                 "Compound 4:  IgG3-723", "Compound 5:  IgG4", "Compound 6:  Total-IgG", 
                 "Compound 7:  IgG1_IS", "Compound 8:  IgG2_IS", "Compound 9:  IgG3_IS", 
                 "Compound 10:  IgG4_IS", "Compound 11:  Total_IgG_IS"), 
      class = "factor"), 
    x = structure(c(11.9452, 10.2922, 10.0745, 19.6632, 4.2135, 3.7465, 0.114358889272131, 0.0653669981293651, 
                    0.0568296675259594, 0.163542587046242, 0.0569370997973496, 0.0253651116474753, 
                    0.957362700265639, 0.63511200840797, 0.564094173665784, 0.831719084616146, 
                    1.35130176331671, 0.677034876484061), 
                  .Dim = c(6L, 3L), 
                  .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("mean", "sd", "cv")))), 
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
  class = "data.frame")
```

Looking at the output we see that it does not represent the data well:

```r
test
#>   Group.1           Group.2      x.mean        x.sd        x.cv
#> 1      P1 Compound 1:  IgG1 11.94520000  0.11435889  0.95736270
#> 2      P2 Compound 1:  IgG1 10.29220000  0.06536700  0.63511201
#> 3      P1 Compound 2:  IgG2 10.07450000  0.05682967  0.56409417
#> 4      P2 Compound 2:  IgG2 19.66320000  0.16354259  0.83171908
#> 5      P1 Compound 3:  IgG3  4.21350000  0.05693710  1.35130176
#> 6      P2 Compound 3:  IgG3  3.74650000  0.02536511  0.67703488
write.table(file="test.csv", test, row.names = F, dec=",", sep = ";")
```

You can get around this with:

```r
newdf <- test[1:2] # extract the first two columns
newdf <- cbind(newdf, test$x) # Add `test$x` as 4 new columns
newdf
#>   Group.1           Group.2    mean         sd        cv
#> 1      P1 Compound 1:  IgG1 11.9452 0.11435889 0.9573627
#> 2      P2 Compound 1:  IgG1 10.2922 0.06536700 0.6351120
#> 3      P1 Compound 2:  IgG2 10.0745 0.05682967 0.5640942
#> 4      P2 Compound 2:  IgG2 19.6632 0.16354259 0.8317191
#> 5      P1 Compound 3:  IgG3  4.2135 0.05693710 1.3513018
#> 6      P2 Compound 3:  IgG3  3.7465 0.02536511 0.6770349
write.table(file="test.csv", newdf, row.names = F, dec=",", sep = ";")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you for your splendid explanation.

Comment: The matrix was somehow introduced in this part:
`ag<-aggregate.data.frame(dfs$Conc.,by=list(dfs$ID , dfs$klass) , FUN=function(x) c( mean=mean(x), sd = sd(x), cv=100*sd(x)/mean(x)))
`
I wonder how I could avoid it?

Comment: The "workaround" in the answer does not help? Or are you simply trying to improve your code. We'll gladly help you. However, you'd have to ask a new question.

Comment: you are correct I was trying to improve my code. I have now a better flow for my needs using DT. Thank you